# How to add clickable button to autocomplete component in primeNg?

Tags: angular, primeng

I try to add clickable button to Autocomplete suggestions item to click it without select an element.

I try to add template refences to div inside ng-template and read them as QueryList item
then listen to changes and when item change I use renderer2 to wrap each`<li>` element into 
and add button beside`<li>` element and add click listener to each button.

```
<ng-template let-subProduct let-rowIndex="rowIndex" pTemplate="item" #templs>
            <div class="autocomplete-item" #temRef
              [style.flex-direction]="translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? 'row-reverse' : 'row'">
              <div class="item-name-barcode"
                [style.flex-direction]="translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? 'row-reverse' : 'row'">
                <div class="item-name-barcode"
                  [style.flex-direction]="translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? 'row-reverse' : 'row'">
                  <strong>{{subProduct.barcode }} </strong>
                  <strong>{{translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? subProduct.arName:subProduct.enName}}</strong>
                </div>
                <span>{{'INVOICES.quantity'|translate}} ({{ subProduct.quantity > 0 ? subProduct.quantity -
                  subProduct.reservedQuantity:subProduct.quantity }})</span>
              </div>
              <em class="m-0">{{translate.currentLang == 'ar' ? subProduct.product.arDescription:subProduct.product.enDescription}}</em>
            </div>
         </ng-template>
```

inside ngAfterViewInit

```
  this.temRef.changes.pipe(map(x => x.toArray())).subscribe(res => {
      this.addButtonToAutoCompleteElement(res)
    })
```